# I'm new to c++, is there an algorithm to find the distance to nearest 0 in a 3d array?

Tags: c++, c++17

In a 3D array, the diagonal elements are 0 i.e. a[k][k][k]=0 for k=1 to 10. I need to fill the remaining matrix with distance to the nearest 0.

I came across the breadth first search, but can i do it without using data structures? (not familiar with data structures)

```
unsigned short d = 10, r = 10, c = 10;
  double*** a = new double** [d];
  for (int i = 0; i < d; ++i) {
      a[i] = new double* [r];
      for (int j = 0; j < r; ++j)
          a[i][j] = new double[c];
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      a[i][i][i] = 0;
  }
```

return a 3d distance array.

Comment: What kind of distance do you mean ? Do you mean taxidistance ?

Comment: manhattan distance

Comment: Why are you using new instead of the standard containers or a specialized library?

Comment: Cause he is new to c++?

Answer (score 0):

Just fill your matrix with this formula for all i, j, k :

```
a[i][j][k] = MAX(i,j,k) - MIN(i,j,k)
```

The Manhattan distance to the diagonal is indeed the difference between the highest index and the lowest one.

This formula is so simple that it seems somewhat magical, but it works !

Answer (score 0):

you can find all zeros and find the closest by calculating the manhattan distance.
another efficient way to this will be to use bfs algorithm. the first zero found in bfs is the closest zero from source.
here is a tutorial for 2d array [sortest distance](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shortest-distance-two-cells-matrix-grid/)